# Como retornar o value numérico de um SelectListItem C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Preciso retornar um List SelectListItem onde a propriedade value de cada item retorne o valor do enum (1, 2...) e não o nome da propriedade (fisica, juridica...). Como faço isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Função

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EnumParaSelectListGenericoNumerico<T>(string tipoCase = null)
{
    var teste = (Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().Select(
        e => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = (tipoCase == null ? ObterDescricaoEnumGenerico<T>(e.ToString()) : (tipoCase.ToUpper() == "U" ? ObterDescricaoEnumGenerico<T>(e.ToString()).ToUpper() : ObterDescricaoEnumGenerico<T>(e.ToString()))),
            Value = e.ToString()
        }
        )).ToList();

    return teste;
}
```

Função Auxiliar

```
public static string ObterDescricaoEnumGenerico<T>(string value)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    var name = Enum.GetNames(type).Where(f => f.Equals(value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).Select(d => d).FirstOrDefault();

    if (name == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    var field = type.GetField(name);
    var customAttribute = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
    return customAttribute.Length > 0 ? ((DescriptionAttribute)customAttribute[0]).Description : name;
}
```

Chamada da função

```
sistemaViewModel.PessoasNaturezas = ExtensaoDeEnumerador.EnumParaSelectListGenericoNumerico<PessoaNatureza>("U").OrderBy(x => x.Text);
```

Enum

```
public enum PessoaNatureza
{
   [Description("FÍSICA")]
   Fisica = 1,
   [Description("JURÍDICA")]
   Juridica = 2
}
```

Comment: não dá pra dar um e.gethashcode()?

Comment: Funcionou brtother  @Lucas Miranda!!! comenta como resposta no post que eu definir como respondido. Obrigado )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme comentado, basta utilizar o comando `getHashCode`, exemplo:

```
var teste = (Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().Select(
        e => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = (tipoCase == null ? ObterDescricaoEnumGenerico<T>(e.ToString()) : (tipoCase.ToUpper() == "U" ? ObterDescricaoEnumGenerico<T>(e.ToString()).ToUpper() : ObterDescricaoEnumGenerico<T>(e.ToString()))),
            Value = e.GetHashCode()
        }
        )).ToList();
```